# How to enumerate an ActiveRecord object without knowing its attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to enumerate Active Record data objects like what `Hash#each` does in Ruby, is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each individual object has accessible [`attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes):

```
model.attributes.each do |attribute, value|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I've found they're getting increasingly difficult to read since the good stuff is often organized into sub-modules, but always have a good API reference bookmarked!